# ESP-IDF installation help

Tags: software-installation, python, dependencies, make

I am trying to run [the hello_world example](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/index.html#step-5-start-a-project) for the [ESP-IDF](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf) (Espressif IoT Development Framework). I'm getting stuck when trying to make the `menuconfig` project configuration utility that shows the Espressif IoT Development Framework Configuration menu.

[image: Espressif IoT Development Framework Configuration menu]

I get the following error message when trying to run `make menuconfig` from the *hello_world* directory:

```
amal@LAPTOP:~/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world$ make menuconfig  
The following Python requirements are not satisfied:
cryptography>=2.1.4
Please refer to the [Get Started](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/) section of the ESP-IDF Programming Guide for setting up the required packages.  
Alternatively, you can run "/usr/bin/python -m pip install --user -r /home/amal/esp/esp-idf/requirements.txt" for resolving the issue.  
make: *** No rule to make target 'check_python_dependencies', needed by 'menuconfig'.  Stop.
```

Comment: I want to solve this issue ... anybody who knows please help

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-cryptography  # for Python 2.x (default)
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3-cryptography # for Python 3.x
```

*Note*: If your default version of Python is 3.x, you may need to run `python2 $(which idf.py) menuconfig` in the [Step 7. Configure section](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/#step-7-configure) of ESP-IDF Programming Guide - Get Started instead.

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 please comment, so that I will add instructions about how to install the python3-cryptography version 2.1.4 for 18.04 in 16.04.